# WPF DataGrid Get All SelectedRows

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid, rows, selected

Have to use free WPF DataGrid (I thought Infragistics libraries are bad, I take it back after this) for this project of mine.

Looks like DataGrid doesnt have clean MVVM Friendly way of getting the list of selectedRows ?

I can data bind to `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSourceFile}"` but this only shows the 1st selected row. Need to be able to get all selected rows.

Any hints to do it cleanly via MVVM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a workaround I created for situations like this that allows you to do `OneWayToSource` Bindings for readonly dependency properties. I call it `PushBinding`.

I made a blog post about it here: [OneWayToSource Binding for ReadOnly Dependency Property](http://meleak.wordpress.com/2011/08/28/onewaytosource-binding-for-readonly-dependency-property/)

To bind `SelectedItems`, you can do this

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ...}">
    <pb:PushBindingManager.PushBindings>
        <pb:PushBinding TargetProperty="SelectedItems" Path="MySelectedItems"/>
    </pb:PushBindingManager.PushBindings>
</DataGrid>
```

And the property in the ViewModel

```
public IList MySelectedItems
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

If you're interested, you can download a demo project using `PushBinding` here: [PushBindingInStyleDemo.zip](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/39657172/Blog/PushBindingInStyleDemo.zip)

Answer (score 2):

There's a [blog post here](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2009/02/how-to-databind-to-selecteditems.html) that describes how to do two-way binding to the SelectedItems property. The example uses a ListBox, but should work just as well with a DataGrid since they both derive from MultiSelector.

The blog post has downloadable sample code.

Comment: It's working with DataGrid but there is a deficient part. When set CanUserAddRows property of DataGrid is true, new row causes thrown an exception because New row has "{NewItemPlaceholder}" as DataContext. Probably, it's easy to solve problem but I am new at WPF. Therefore, I couldn't do it.